# xtensa-esp32-elf-g++: fatal error: -fuse-linker-plugin, but liblto_plugin.so not found

Tags: visual-studio, esp32, platformio

I am hitting the above error on visual studio when uploading code for an esp32 using Platformio. This is a recent problem and comes after a fresh install Monterey OS for a macbook pro. I am using pyenv and python 3.8.5 if that makes a difference. I am able to use platformio to upload code to an Arduino Uno.

Here is a snippet from the verbose listing of the upload process:
Processing esp32doit-devkit-v1 (platform: espressif32; board: esp32doit-devkit-v1; framework: arduino; monitor_speed: 115200; lib_deps: arduino-libraries/Stepper@^1.1.3)

---

CONFIGURATION: //docs.platformio.org/page/boards/espressif32/esp32doit-devkit-v1.html
PLATFORM: Espressif 32 (3.3.2) > DOIT ESP32 DEVKIT V1
HARDWARE: ESP32 240MHz, 320KB RAM, 4MB Flash
DEBUG: Current (esp-prog) External (esp-prog, iot-bus-jtag, jlink, minimodule, olimex-arm-usb-ocd, olimex-arm-usb-ocd-h, olimex-arm-usb-tiny-h, olimex-jtag-tiny, tumpa)
PACKAGES:

- framework-arduinoespressif32 @ 3.10006.210326 (1.0.6)
- tool-esptoolpy @ 1.30100.210531 (3.1.0)
- tool-mkspiffs @ 2.230.0 (2.30)
- toolchain-xtensa32 @ 2.50200.97 (5.2.0)
  xtensa-esp32-elf-g++ -o "/Users/person/Documents/PlatformIO/Projects/esp32L298/esp32_360/src/esp32_28byj.ino.cpp" -x c++ -fpreprocessed -dD -E "/var/folders/2d/q2nqrsy122zgdzlnwkz6rgtw0000gn/T/tmpeek2x4mq"
  LDF: Library Dependency Finder -> bit_ly/configure-pio-ldf
  LDF Modes: Finder ~ chain, Compatibility ~ soft
  Found 29 compatible libraries
  Scanning dependencies...
  Dependency Graph
  |-- Stepper @ 1.1.3 (License: Unknown, Path: /Users/person/Documents/PlatformIO/Projects/esp32L298/esp32_360/.pio/libdeps/esp32doit-devkit-v1/Stepper)
  Building in release mode
  xtensa-esp32-elf-g++ -o .pio/build/esp32doit-devkit-v1/src/esp32_28byj.ino.cpp.o -c -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions -std=gnu++11 -Os -g3 -Wall -nostdlib -Wpointer-arith -Wno-error=unused-but-set-variable -Wno-error=unused-variable -mlongcalls -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fstrict-volatile-bitfields -Wno-error=deprecated-declarations -Wno-error=unused-function -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-sign-compare -fstack-protector -fexceptions -Werror=reorder -DPLATFORMIO=60113 -DARDUINO_ESP32_DEV -DESP32 -DESP_PLATFORM -DF_CPU=240000000L -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DMBEDTLS_CONFIG_FILE="mbedtls/esp_config.h" -DARDUINO=10805 -DARDUINO_ARCH_ESP32 -DARDUINO_VARIANT="doitESP32devkitV1" "-DARDUINO_BOARD="DOIT ESP32 DEVKIT V1"" -Iinclude -Isrc -I.pio/libdeps/esp32doit-devkit-v1/Stepper/src -I/Users/person/.platformio/packages/framework-arduinoespressif32/tools/sdk/include/config -I/Users/person/.platformio/packages/framework-arduinoespressif32/tools/sdk/include/app_trace -I/Users/person/.platformio/packages/framework-arduinoespressif32/tools/sdk/include/app_update -I/Users/person/.platformio/packages/framework-arduinoespressif32/tools/sdk/include/asio -I/Users/person/.platformio/packages/framework-arduinoespressif32/tools/sdk/include/bootloader_support -I/Users/person/.platformio/packages/framework-arduinoespressif32/tools/sdk/include/bt -I/Users/person/.platformio/packages/framework-arduinoespressif32/tools/sdk/include/coap -I/Users/person/.platformio/packages/framework-arduinoespressif32/tools/sdk/include/console -I/Users/person/.platformio/packages/framework-arduinoespressif32/tools/sdk/include/driver -I/Users/person/.platformio/packages/framework-arduinoespressif32/tools/sdk/include/efuse -I/Users/person/.platformio/packages/framework-arduinoespressif32/tools/sdk/include/esp-tls -I/Users/person/.platformio/packages/framework-arduinoespressif32/tools/sdk/include/esp32 -I/Users/person/.platformio/packages/framework-arduinoespressif32/tools/sdk/include/esp_adc_cal -I/Users/person/.platformio/packages/framework-arduinoespressif32/tools/sdk/include/esp_event -I/Users/person/.platformio/packages/framework-arduinoespressif32/tools/sdk/include/esp_http_client -I/Users/person/.platformio/packages/framework-arduinoespressif32/tools/sdk/include/esp_http_server -I/Users/person/.platformio/packages/framework-arduinoespressif32/tools/sdk/include/esp_https_ota -I/Users/person/.platformio/packages/framework-arduinoespressif32/tools/sdk/include/esp_https_server -I/Users/person/.platformio/packages/framework-arduinoespressif32/tools/sdk/include/esp_ringbuf -I/Users/person/.platformio/packages/framework-arduinoespressif32/tools/sdk/include/esp_websocket_client -I/Users/person/.platformio/packages/framework-arduinoespressif32/tools/sdk/include/espcoredump -I/Users/person/.platformio/packages/framework-arduinoespressif32/tools/sdk/include/ethernet -I/Users/person/.platformio/packages/framework-arduinoespressif32/tools/sdk/include/expat -I/Users/person/.platformio/packages/framework-arduinoespressif32/tools/sdk/include/fatfs -I/Users/person/.platformio/packages/framework-arduinoespressif32/tools/sdk/include/freemodbus -I/Users/person/.platformio/packages/framework-arduinoespressif32/tools/sdk/include/freertos -I/Users/person/.platformio/packages/framework-arduinoespressif32/tools/sdk/include/heap -I/Users/person/.platformio/packages/framework-arduinoespressif32/tools/sdk/include/idf_test -I/Users/person/.platformio/packages/framework-arduinoespressif32/tools/sdk/include/jsmn -I/Users/person/.platformio/packages/framework-arduinoespressif32/tools/sdk/include/json -I/Users/person/.platformio/packages/framework-arduinoespressif32/tools/sdk/include/libsodium -I/Users/person/.platformio/packages/framework-arduinoespressif32/tools/sdk/include/log -I/Users/person/.platformio/packages/framework-arduinoespressif32/tools/sdk/include/lwip -I/Users/person/.platformio/packages/framework-arduinoespressif32/tools/sdk/include/mbedtls -I/Users/person/.platformio/packages/framework-arduinoespressif32/tools/sdk/include/mdns -I/Users/person/.platformio/packages/framework-arduinoespressif32/tools/sdk/include/micro-ecc -I/Users/person/.platformio/packages/framework-arduinoespressif32/tools/sdk/include/mqtt -I/Users/person/.platformio/packages/framework-arduinoespressif32/tools/sdk/include/newlib -I/Users/person/.platformio/packages/framework-arduinoespressif32/tools/sdk/include/nghttp -I/Users/person/.platformio/packages/framework-arduinoespressif32/tools/sdk/include/nvs_flash -I/Users/person/.platformio/packages/framework-arduinoespressif32/tools/sdk/include/openssl -I/Users/person/.platformio/packages/framework-arduinoespressif32/tools/sdk/include/protobuf-c -I/Users/person/.platformio/packages/framework-arduinoespressif32/tools/sdk/include/protocomm -I/Users/person/.platformio/packages/framework-arduinoespressif32/tools/sdk/include/pthread -I/Users/person/.platformio/packages/framework-arduinoespressif32/tools/sdk/include/sdmmc -I/Users/person/.platformio/packages/framework-arduinoespressif32/tools/sdk/include/smartconfig_ack -I/Users/person/.platformio/packages/framework-arduinoespressif32/tools/sdk/include/soc -I/Users/person/.platformio/packages/framework-arduinoespressif32/tools/sdk/include/spi_flash -I/Users/person/.platformio/packages/framework-arduinoespressif32/tools/sdk/include/spiffs -I/Users/person/.platformio/packages/framework-arduinoespressif32/tools/sdk/include/tcp_transport -I/Users/person/.platformio/packages/framework-arduinoespressif32/tools/sdk/include/tcpip_adapter -I/Users/person/.platformio/packages/framework-arduinoespressif32/tools/sdk/include/ulp -I/Users/person/.platformio/packages/framework-arduinoespressif32/tools/sdk/include/unity -I/Users/person/.platformio/packages/framework-arduinoespressif32/tools/sdk/include/vfs -I/Users/person/.platformio/packages/framework-arduinoespressif32/tools/sdk/include/wear_levelling -I/Users/person/.platformio/packages/framework-arduinoespressif32/tools/sdk/include/wifi_provisioning -I/Users/person/.platformio/packages/framework-arduinoespressif32/tools/sdk/include/wpa_supplicant -I/Users/person/.platformio/packages/framework-arduinoespressif32/tools/sdk/include/xtensa-debug-module -I/Users/person/.platformio/packages/framework-arduinoespressif32/tools/sdk/include/esp-face -I/Users/person/.platformio/packages/framework-arduinoespressif32/tools/sdk/include/esp32-camera -I/Users/person/.platformio/packages/framework-arduinoespressif32/tools/sdk/include/esp-face -I/Users/person/.platformio/packages/framework-arduinoespressif32/tools/sdk/include/fb_gfx -I/Users/person/.platformio/packages/framework-arduinoespressif32/cores/esp32 -I/Users/person/.platformio/packages/framework-arduinoespressif32/variants/doitESP32devkitV1 src/esp32_28byj.ino.cpp
  xtensa-esp32-elf-g++ -o .pio/build/esp32doit-devkit-v1/firmware.elf -T esp32_out.ld -nostdlib -Wl,-static -u call_user_start_cpu0 -Wl,--undefined=uxTopUsedPriority -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,-EL -T esp32.project.ld -T esp32.rom.ld -T esp32.peripherals.ld -T esp32.rom.libgcc.ld -T esp32.rom.spiram_incompatible_fns.ld -u ld_include_panic_highint_hdl -u __cxa_guard_dummy -u __cxx_fatal_exception .pio/build/esp32doit-devkit-v1/src/esp32_28byj.ino.cpp.o -L.pio/build/esp32doit-devkit-v1 -L/Users/person/.platformio/packages/framework-arduinoespressif32/tools/sdk/lib -L/Users/person/.platformio/packages/framework-arduinoespressif32/tools/sdk/ld -Wl,--start-group .pio/build/esp32doit-devkit-v1/lib0c8/libStepper.a .pio/build/esp32doit-devkit-v1/libFrameworkArduinoVariant.a .pio/build/esp32doit-devkit-v1/libFrameworkArduino.a -lgcc -lesp_websocket_client -lwpa2 -ldetection -lesp_https_server -lwps -lhal -lconsole -lpe -lsoc -lsdmmc -lpthread -llog -lesp_http_client -ljson -lmesh -lesp32-camera -lnet80211 -lwpa_supplicant -lc -lmqtt -lcxx -lesp_https_ota -lulp -lefuse -lpp -lmdns -lbt -lwpa -lspiffs -lheap -limage_util -lunity -lrtc -lmbedtls -lface_recognition -lnghttp -ljsmn -lopenssl -lcore -lfatfs -lm -lprotocomm -lsmartconfig -lxtensa-debug-module -ldl -lesp_event -lesp-tls -lfd -lespcoredump -lesp_http_server -lfr -lsmartconfig_ack -lwear_levelling -ltcp_transport -llwip -lphy -lvfs -lcoap -lesp32 -llibsodium -lbootloader_support -ldriver -lcoexist -lasio -lod -lmicro-ecc -lesp_ringbuf -ldetection_cat_face -lapp_update -lespnow -lface_detection -lapp_trace -lnewlib -lbtdm_app -lwifi_provisioning -lfreertos -lfreemodbus -lethernet -lnvs_flash -lspi_flash -lc_nano -lexpat -lfb_gfx -lprotobuf-c -lesp_adc_cal -ltcpip_adapter -lstdc++ -Wl,--end-group
  xtensa-esp32-elf-g++: fatal error: -fuse-linker-plugin, but liblto_plugin.so not found
  compilation terminated.
  *** [.pio/build/esp32doit-devkit-v1/firmware.elf] Error 1
  ================================================================== [FAILED] Took 2.52 seconds ==================================================================

- The terminal process "platformio 'run', '--verbose', '--target', 'upload', '--environment', 'esp32doit-devkit-v1'" terminated with exit code: 1.
- Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.

I have tried the following with no success:

1. sudo cp /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/13.2.0/lib/gcc/13/libstdc++.6.dylib /opt/osxcross/target/x86_64-apple-darwin12/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
2. installing esp-idf tools visual studio extension